# Modal window disappears after redirect. Angular

Tags: html, angular, routes, ngrx

I need your help. I have a modal that I'm trying to show right after login. My effect and code inside `ngOnInit` only fire once, after I've logged in. This code is not working correctly for me, because my condition for showing the modal window is true, but immediately after showing my modal, a redirect happens, regarding the conditions in the effect, and the modal window immediately disappears. Please tell me where the error is in the code? Why does my modal disappear after a redirect and how to fix it? Thank you very much

html

```
<modalSlideUp [isModalShow]="modalIsShown">
 <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="stayInTheSystem">
      <h4> Don`t ask me again </h4>
      <button> Yes </button>
      <button> No </button>
 </form>
</modalSlideUp>
```

typescript

```
 _modalIsShown: boolean = false;

 get modalIsShown(): boolean {
   return this._modalIsShown;
 }

 set modalIsShown(value: boolean) {
   console.log(value, 'value in setter'); // true
   this._modalIsShown = true;
 }


ngOnInit() {
   this.effects.AuthenticationSuccess.subscribe((data) => 
     let isModalShow: boolean =
      (
        this.tokenService.getUserSavedIsa(this.user?.id) === true ||
        localStorage.getItem('userRecords') === null ||
        localStorage.getItem('dontAskAgain') === 'false'
      );
      this.modalIsShown = isModalShow;
      setTimeout(() => {
         console.log(this.isTokenModalWindowOpened, 'timeout'); // true
       }, 5000)
   })

}
```

effects

```
AuthenticationSuccess: Observable<any> = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(idenityActions.ActionTypes.AUTHENICATION_SUCCESS),
  tap((user:any) => {

    const savedUrl = localStorage.getItem('intendedUrl');

      if (!(user.payload as AuthenticateResponseModel).isAuthenticated) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/non-activate", { skipLocationChange: false });
      } else if (!savedUrl && user.payload.firstSetup === false) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
      } else if (savedUrl && user.payload.firstSetup === false) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(savedUrl);
        setTimeout(() => {
          localStorage.removeItem('savedUrl');
        }, 3000)
      } else if (savedUrl && user.payload.firstSetup === true) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-profile/settings');
      }

  })
),{ dispatch: false });
```

Comment: Are you using a library for the modal? which one?

Comment: Do you want to show the modal *after* the redirect? or immediately after login? or does it not matter as long as it appears and stays visible?

Comment: @wlf After my login, my request immediately goes through and the effect is executed 1 time. There are conditions inside my effect - depending on the answer that came, routing should take place to a specific page. After logging in, I must have a modal that asks whether to stay in the system or not, and it doesn't matter before or after routing. The main thing is that it appears and does not disappear by itself, because the user closes it by choosing his choice.

Comment: and are you using a library for the modal as per first question?

Comment: My guess is you have placed the modalSlideUp inside of a component which is being rendered using router-outlet. but i can't say for sure what's the structure from the section you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep eye on whether the redirect has occurred or not.
try this and let me know.

```
  _modalIsShown: boolean = false;
    _redirectOccurred: boolean = false;
    
    get modalIsShown(): boolean {
      return this._modalIsShown;
    }
    
    set modalIsShown(value: boolean) {
      console.log(value, 'value in setter'); // true
      this._modalIsShown = value;
    }
    
    ngOnInit() {
      this.effects.AuthenticationSuccess.subscribe((data) => {
        if (!this._redirectOccurred) {
          let isModalShow: boolean =
            (
              this.tokenService.getUserSavedIsa(this.user?.id) === true ||
              localStorage.getItem('userRecords') === null ||
              localStorage.getItem('dontAskAgain') === 'false'
            );
          this.modalIsShown = isModalShow;
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.isTokenModalWindowOpened, 'timeout'); // true
          }, 5000);
        }
      });
    
      // Set the redirect occurred flag to true after the modal is shown
      this.effects.Redirect.subscribe(() => {
        this._redirectOccurred = true;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but there is no Redirect effect in my ngrx effects. I thought this could be solved with NavigationStart or NavigationEnd. Thank you very much for your reply, but this is not what is needed

Answer (score 0):

You might want to leverage [`Router.events`](https://angular.io/api/router/Event) to listen for navigation events and handle the modal visibility accordingly.

For instance, adjust your component to listen for `NavigationEnd` events and make sure the modal is shown prior to any navigation occurring:

```js
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

// existing code

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  _modalIsShown: boolean = false;
  _navigationEnded: boolean = false;

  get modalIsShown(): boolean {
    return this._modalIsShown;
  }

  set modalIsShown(value: boolean) {
    console.log(value, 'value in setter'); // true
    this._modalIsShown = value;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private effects: YourEffects, private tokenService: TokenService) {
    // Listen for navigation end events
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this._navigationEnded = true;
        if (this._modalIsShown) {
          // handle modal closure or other actions here
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.effects.AuthenticationSuccess.subscribe((data) => {
      if (!this._navigationEnded) {
        let isModalShow: boolean =
          (
            this.tokenService.getUserSavedIsa(this.user?.id) === true ||
            localStorage.getItem('userRecords') === null ||
            localStorage.getItem('dontAskAgain') === 'false'
          );
        this.modalIsShown = isModalShow;
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this.isTokenModalWindowOpened, 'timeout'); // true
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`Router` and `NavigationEnd` come from `@angular/router`.
Inside the constructor, you can subscribe to `router.events` to listen for instances of `NavigationEnd`, setting `_navigationEnded` to `true` when navigation ends. This flag helps to track whether navigation has ended.
Inside `ngOnInit`, check `_navigationEnded` to decide whether or not to show the modal. If navigation has ended, you can assume that the modal should not be shown.

If needed, other actions can be taken within the `router.events.subscribe` block to manage the modal's visibility or other behavior when navigation occurs.